# Getting the right data but not where I expect it to be

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, ecmascript-next

My code is working. But I'm pretty sure that there is an easier way to do it. The way it is now, I can get the result I need by accessing the '_v' key inside my Promise. That's why I think I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code:

file1.js

```
import * as Utils from '../js/utils';

albumsArray() {
    this.albums = Utils.getAlbums(this.user, this.token);
}
```

utils.js

```
export async function getAlbums(user, token){
  let store = []
  let data = await axios.get(`https://api.imgur.com/3/account/${user}/albums/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    response.data.data.map( data => store.push(data))
  })

  return store || [];
}
```

So, the way it is now, I get the result I want in the albums['_v'].

Obs: albums(this.albums) is a promise when I log it, and _v is the key where is the data I need. What I'm doing wrong. How can I make my code look better?

Thanks

Comment: At the top level you always need to deal with a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about async/await is that you get the actual value instead of the promise... You can do it like this:

```
export async function getAlbums(user, token){
  let response = await axios.get(`https://api.imgur.com/3/account/${user}/albums/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  })
  return response.data.data || [];
}
```

You are pushing everything inside response.data.data into store... why not return response.data.data itself?

Then file1.js should also use async/await so you get the array instead of a promise...

```
async albumsArray() {
    this.albums = await Utils.getAlbums(this.user, this.token);
}
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Great answer. I just moved the response.data.data inside the file 1, and added a try and catch, to handle errors:

    try{
      let store = await Utils.getAlbums(this.user, this.token);
      this.albums = store.data.data.map(data => Album.fromJson(this, data));
    } catch(err) {
      (...)
    }